# Sharepoint - display bug in javascript edited newform.aspx ( wss 3.0 )

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I took the generated newform.aspx file that has a select-field with 3 options.

I now added some js/jquery code to display different fields for options 1/2/3 by taking the internal field name of the select-field and looking up what option is selected and change the displayed fields.

That worked perfect for a while for intranet use. Now i added some new users that will access only this list from an external connection.

So i gave them only rights to add/edit/delete things on this one list. no other permissions given to them.

If i now login with one of those users, the whole javascript thing gets ignored.
if i log back to my account it works.

The code does nothing but look up the value in the select field and display/hide other fields according to the selection.

The javascript i used is based on the code found on [this site](http://sharepointjavascript.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/dynamic-expandcollapse-fields-or-array-of-fields/)

The only difference is that the users have different permission levels, but i cant see any permission level operations going on with the script.

it just displays all fields and ignores the hide/unhide parts.

its running on wss 3.0.

I'd appreciate any help and/or suggestions to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the link the js files are hosted in a document library. Do your new users have read permissions on that library?

Comment: oh yeah forgot to mention i uploaded the file into List/Listname/ folder where all the form files are in.
Does sharepoint handle permissions directly for files and not for folders?

Comment: I think the js files should be fine where you have put them. It might still be worth checking the permissions of the users against the js files though. You might also want to check that the js isn't trying to access content anywhere else besides the intended list.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that they also need the following permission in order to view the new item and edit item pages...

```
View Application Pages  -  View forms, views, and application pages. Enumerate lists.
```

This solved my issue. Hope it helps you.